# Javascript - text input to icon

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a simple web application. Like in Facebook chat when I enter "(Y)" it turns into the thumbs up icon. Similarly I am trying to do something like that with the following code. But it is not working for me. I am not expert with JavaScript. I need some help that what's wrong with the code?

And I made the code in a way that if i enter "y" it will return LIKE. I want to know how to show an icon after "y" input.

```
 <html>
        <head>
            <title>Emogic</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <input type="text" id="input">
        <input onclick="appear()" type="submit">
        <p id="output"></p>


        <script>
        function appear(){

            var value = document.getElementByid("input").value
            var result = document.getElementById("output").innerHTML
            if(value == "y"){
                result = "LIKE"
            }
            else if(value == ""){
                alert("You must enter a valid character.");
            }
            else{
                alert("Character not recognised.");
            }
        }

        </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: An `<input>` does not support this functionality. It's very likely a `<div contenteditable>` that you seek.

Comment: what type of icon? A icon like in fontawesome, a characterr icon like √ , a png?

Comment: A few errors : it's `document.getElementById()`, with a capital `I`in `Id`. `result` will be a string, containing the innerHTML of your element, but not a pointer to this `innerHTML` : when you then set `result` to an other value, it won't change the element's `innerHTML` as you expected. So you need `var out = document.getElementById("output"); var result = out.innerHTML` and after `out.innerHTML = "LIKE"`

Comment: @MadaraUchiha what do you mean by "An <input> does not support this functionality" you can change input's value as you would do with contentEditable div's innerHTML. Also, Op is copying the input's value to a div so no problem to do any computation he wants

Comment: The code is very short and easy. If you kindly read once you will understand that what do I want. But I am not getting expected result. It is not working. 
I want that if I enter "y" in the textbox and click submit, the paragraph below will show "LIKE". But now nothing works. And for icon I meant to say that if I get a solution to the problem I want to show an icon below instead of the "LIKE".

Comment: @AbeerHussain did you tried to make the corrections I proposed in my comment? You'll be able to get `LIKE` in the output if you do enter `y` in the input. For the icon, it is an other problem, and it would need more info as davidkonrad asked you.

Comment: @Kaiido Yes i tried the changes you asked for...but no work again.

Comment: I am not worried about icon right now. if I get the text that will be good for now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93297/discussion-between-abeer-hussain-and-kaiido).

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues/typo in your code :
it's `document.getElementById()`, with a capital `I` in `Id`.
`result` will be a string, containing the `innerHTML` of your element, but not a pointer to this `innerHTML` : when you then set `result` to an other value, it won't change the element's `innerHTML` as you expected. So you need to create a pointer to the element, and then set its `innerHTML` from the pointer.

The quick fix of your code would then be  :

```js
function appear() {

  var value = document.getElementById("input").value;
  var output = document.getElementById("output");
  if (value == "y") {
    output.innerHTML = "LIKE";
  } else if (value == "") {
    alert("You must enter a valid character.");
  } else {
    alert("Character not recognised.");
  }

}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" value="y">
<input onclick="appear()" type="submit">
<p id="output"></p>
```

But you'll find out that your user will have to enter exactly `"y"` and only `"y"` for it to work.

I think you should use instead `String.replace()` method with a regular expression to get all occurences of a pattern, i.e, for `"(Y)"` it could be

```js
function appear() {
  
  var value = document.getElementById("input").value;
  var output = document.getElementById("output");
  // The Regular Expression we're after
  var reg = /\(Y\)/g;
  // your replacement string
  var replacement = 'LIKE';
  // if we found one or more times the pattern
  if (value.match(reg).length > 0) {
    output.innerHTML = value.replace(reg, replacement);
  } else if (value == "") {
    alert("You must enter a valid character.");
  } else {
    alert("Character not recognised.");
  }
  
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" value="I (Y) it (Y) that">
<input onclick="appear()" type="submit">
<p id="output"></p>
```